# How to save weights in .npy file in a similar format which is being used in CNN?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am using a github repository containing a trained CNN with weight parameters given in `.npy` file. Model is loading the weights and using the model parameters like this:-

```
model = CNN_Model(batch_size)
filename = "weight_file.npy"
dtype = torch.FloatTensor    
model.load_state_dict(load_weights(model, weight_file, dtype))
```

And `load_weights` is defined as:-

```
def load_weights(model, filename, dtype):
    model_params = model.state_dict()
    data_dict = np.load(filename, encoding='latin1').item()
    model_params["conv1.weight"] = torch.from_numpy(data_dict["conv1"] ["weights"]).type(dtype).permute(3,2,0,1)
    model_params["conv1.bias"] = torch.from_numpy(data_dict["conv1"]["biases"]).type(dtype)
    model_params["bn1.weight"] = torch.from_numpy(data_dict["bn_conv1"]["scale"]).type(dtype)
    model_params["bn1.bias"] = torch.from_numpy(data_dict["bn_conv1"]["offset"]).type(dtype)
    return model_params
```

I have added a training module to it and trying to fine tune the weights  on my own dataset. After training i want to save new weights in `.npy` file with same indexes of `data_dict` as there were in previously loaded weight file so i can use them again for CNN model.

How should i do indexing with similar names before saving the data_dict array using:

```
np.save("trained_weight_file.npy", data_dict)
```

EDIT 1:-
So on recommendation of @[a-d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11192099/a-d) i did

```
data_dict = model.state_dict()
```

What it did is it saved all the weights with index of `model_params`. Output of `print data_dict` was:-

```
OrderedDict([('conv1.weight', tensor([[[[....]]]])), ('conv1.bias', tensor([....])), , ('bn1.weight', tensor([....])), ('bn1.bias', tensor([....]))])
```

But what i need is to store in `data_dict` index so i can read it with same algo from `.npy` file. Also i tried returning `data_dict` along with `model_params` from `load_weights` definition and then tried to use `data_dict = model.state_dict()` but it gave me error on `model.load_state_dict(load_weights(model, weight_file, dtype))' line that is:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  model.load_state_dict(load_weights(model, weight_file, dtype))
  state_dict = state_dict.copy()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like `data_dict = model.state_dict()`.

You can read the official documentation with an example of the output of `state_dict()` [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#).
There is a [github repository](https://github.com/iapatil/depth-semantic-fully-conv/blob/master/main.py) that is the base of the github repository from which you might have your code. This repository uses `model.state_dict()` to store the values as well.

Comment: Thanks for the github repo. But i asked the question to know how should i do something like this  'data_dict["conv1"] ["weights"]) = model_params["conv1.weight"].numpy()'. I have just written 4 lines of weight retrieval, there are some hundred lines like this. So one way could be to write every line something like i have written or other may be someway to read the index of saved weight array in .npy file and store new weight arrays in it. Actually i am looking for syntax to do any of them but couldnt do so. Second method feels better as i just have to make a loop.

Comment: Did you try the `data_dict = model.state_dict()`? It should fill all these fields automatically. What are you getting with that approach?

Comment: I have edited with follow up to your recommendation. Please any further tip.